# Vim regex captures part of group pattern at the end of the string

Tags: regex, vim

I'm fairly new to Vim and regex. I have a file that looks something like this :

```
parent = 0001,,,lje1 
parent 0001 = category = 0002,,,ljef
parent 0001 = category = 0003,,,ljex4
parent = 0004,,,lxen 
parent 0004 = category = 0005,,,lxvr
```

I am looking to get the last set of numbers, commas and the code at the end of each line . If I use the following regex:

```
/[0-9]*,*l[a-z0-9]*$/
```

It matches the correct part on each line... numbers, comma and code. But if I try to do a replacement as such:

```
%s/.*\([0-9]*,*l[a-z0-9]*$\)/\1
```

I am just left with something that looks like this:

```
lje1 
ljef
ljex4
lxen 
lxvr
```

What I would like to be left with is this:

```
0001,,,lje1 
0002,,,ljef
0003,,,ljex4
0004,,,lxen 
0005,,,lxvr
```

If anyone has any idea of what I'm doing wrong, please help. I have searched and checked other posts but I can't seem to find a solution.

Cheers

Comment: just a comment, you probably better off replacing * with +

Comment: Any reason in particular, Im going to go read up on this now..

Comment: your regex will also match letter **l**  by itself. * mean 0 to many where + means 1 to many. depending on your need, you can choose one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need lazy matching with `.\{-}` instead of `.*`:

```
%s/.\{-}\([0-9]*,*l[a-z0-9]*$\)/\1
```

Comment: Damn.. so simple.. Thanks so much! will accept this answer as soon as it lets me!

Comment: Thank you, much appreciated! I have only just been allowed to upvote answers as of this very moment, so there you go, you get my first haha!

Answer (score 4):

Just replace the all the chars upto the last space character with an empty string.

```
/.* /
```

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/xR3jO0/1)

Comment: Good shout, I solved it with the answer below but thanks, didnt even think of this!